# jQuery: How to extend an extension?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-widgets

I have seen that jQuery's plugins may be extened this way:

```
$.ui.plugin.add('draggable', 'zIndex', {
    start: function(event, ui) { //... }
})
```

I am wondering whether it is possible to extend an extension? So, say, I want to change something (not everything) in the zIndex extension of the draggable plugin, that is, to place some code of my own at the very beginning of the start callback function. How would I go about it? How to access that function to proxy it?

Answer (score 1):

Along these lines:

```
(function ($) {
    function proxyPlugin(plugin, callback, option, func) {
        $.each($.ui[plugin].prototype.plugins[callback], function (k, v) {
            if (v[0] == option) {
                var fn = v[1];

                v[1] = function () {
                    func.apply(this, arguments);

                    fn.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    proxyPlugin('draggable', 'start', 'zIndex', function (e, ui) {
        // we are in our custom function that will be triggered before the original one.
        // our custom function receives all the arguments the original one has.
        // for example, let's add a property by the name of foo to the ui object. 
        ui.foo = true;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: looks nice, but I would add some verification that `$.ui[plugin]` is not  `null` and stuff like that for other properties being accessed. And checking whether `fn` is function is also required, I think.